# Equality comparison against 0 not working

Tags: javascript

```js
function compare() {
  var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box3").value);
  var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box4").value);
  var display = document.getElementById("box5");
  if (value1 === 0 || value2 === 0) {
    display.value = "You have entered zero";
  } else if (value1 == value2) {
    display.value = "The numbers are the same";
  } else if (value1 % value2 == 0) {
    display.value = "The first is divisible by the second";
  } else if (value2 % value1 == 0) {
    display.value = "The second is divisible by the first";
  } else {
    display.value = "They are not divisible";
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Enter two numbers and we will tell you if they are evenly divisble</p>
<p> Enter your first number:</p> <input type="text" id="box3">
<p> Enter your second number: </p> <input type="text" id="box4">
<button id="compareValue" onclick="compare()">Compare Values</button>
<p> Output will appear here: </p> <input text="type" id="box5" disabled>
```

In the above code, enter 89.09 in the first number input and 0.05 into the second number input. Clicking on compare values returns

> **You have entered zero**

[image: Equality comparison against 0 not working]

The question is why?

Comment: The `parseInt()` function returns an **integer**.  `0.05` is therefore 0.

Comment: This mysteriously looking turned out to be a very stupid question :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing `0.05` as an integer produces `0`:

> The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an
> **integer** of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral
> systems).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

You're probably looking for [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead:

```
var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box3").value);
var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box4").value);
```

Alternatively, it may be better to cast it as a number using either `Number()` or the `+` prefix operator as @pointy has suggested below:

```
let value1 = Number(document.getElementById('box3').value);
```

Comment: I generally recommend that people use `Number()` or the `+` prefix operator, because the `parse` functions will accept input like `123.45hello world` without complaint.

Comment: @ZameerAnsari we all have a bad day sometimes ;)